# Typo3 formhandler validate email suffix

Tags: forms, validation, typo3

i installed the Typo3 extension "Formhandler" and everything is working.

But i have the wish tha a Form can only be send if the E-Mail suffix is equal to 3 others.

Example,
my Form have a field "Email: ***_*__*_*___**",
and the Form should only be submitted if the Field contains

```
<something>@support.example.com
<something>@web.example.com
<something>@news.example.com
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the pregMatch error check.

```
validators {
  1.class = Validator_Default
  1.config.fieldConf {
    email.errorCheck {
      1 = pregMatch
      1.value = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@(support|web|news)+\.(example)+\.(com)\b/
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this a regular expression?

Comment: Yes, this is a regular expression. Formhandler can use perl regular expressions as described here http://www.typo3-formhandler.com/documentation/error-checks/strings/pregmatch/